# Object disappears (invisible) in sculpt mode

Tags: eevee-render-engine, sculpting

I don't know why, but my model disappears in sculpt mode. I tried ALT+H and Local View, but nothing helps. Maybe someone has any idea?

Blend File:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PBoX0FEH7VjAUCI3fL_SA8dBUKCW-7IP/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete the color atribute in the object data properties

[image]

Comment: nice, so what was the problem with the color attribute, how did it make the object invisible?

Comment: Yeah, this seems weird to me. And these get exported to FBX too I think, since I exported and reimported the model and still had the problem. Thanks anyway for the fix :)

Comment: I don't know exactly why it happened, but since this is an exported model I believe the color data was corrupt or not supported by blender (most unlikely) @moonboots